# res.sendFile forces file to be downloaded

Tags: node.js, express

I'm trying to send an image to be displayed fullscreen in the browser, but the problem is that the following code forces the file to be sent as an attachment (downloaded), similar to `res.download()` rather than displaying the image:

```
res.sendFile(file, {root: path.join(__dirname, '../storage')})
```

Is there a way to display the image without making forcing it to be downloaded or without reading the raw file?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found that the problem was that the file didn't have any file extension. As `res.sendFile()` attempts to automatically set the content-type header, this was causing issues which made the file download rather than be displayed.

If files have no file extension you can manually set the `Content-Type` header for `res.sendFiel()` like so:

```
res.sendFile(file, {headers: {'Content-Type': 'image/jpeg'}})
```

Which will cause the image to be displayed correctly.

Comment: This worked ! But I don't understand, why setting headers before sendFile didn't work. I set them using: `res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html')`

Answer (score 1):

For express 4.x you need to:

```
res.set('Content-Type', mimeType); // mimeType eg. 'image/bmp'
res.sendFile( file );
```